# The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem Vs The Runge's Phenomenon

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, interpolation

I am learning about different interpolation methods in my internship. Today as I was looking [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) article on Wikipedia to learn about the Runge's Phenomenon exhibited by [Polynomial Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). I noticed that [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) is contradicted by Runge's Phenomenon:

Weierstrass Theorem:  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \max_{a \leq x \leq b} | f(x) -P_n(x)| \right) = 0.$$

Runge's Phenomenon for Equidistant partition of interval: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \max_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} | f(x) -P_n(x)| \right) = +\infty. $$ This is the first time I am seeing a theorem being contradicted. But I am pretty sure that I have misunderstood something because a theorem, by definition, should always be correct, isn't it? Please clarify my misunderstanding. Thanks .

Comment: the $P_n$ in the second statement refers to a very specific sequence of polynomials, a sequence which is not necessarily the same as the sequence in the first statement

Comment: can you be more precise in your argument?

Comment: runge's phenomenon for (say) $1/(1+x^2)$ states that the sequence of interpolation polynomials computed with equidistant nodes has uniform error growing without bound. so *that particular* sequence of approximating polynomials isn't good. the weierstrass' theorem says there is *some* good sequence of approximating polynomials. there's no guarantee that it's the ones in the interpolation process

Comment: @exitingcorpse Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can see this as essentially a parsing error (the $P_n$ in the two statements refer to two different things).

Stone-Weierstrass tells us that every continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$ can be approximated arbitrarily closely by *some* sequence of polynomials.

We contrast this to polynomial interpolation: this is a *specific method* for generating a sequence of polynomials that will approximate our data set. If our data set was just the outputs of some continuous function, we would hope that the sequence of polynomials would approximate it arbitrarily closely as we generate them of higher and higher degree. The Runge phenomenon says that this is too optimistic: approximating $1/(1+x^2)$ over $[-5,5]$ with equidistant nodes does not converge in the way we want.

Once we've identified that it is possible for polynomial interpolation to fail, we begin to investigate its various failures and successes. [The section on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Convergence_properties) discusses what happens when we look at other sample point generation schemes.

Answer (score 3):

In actually his [most recent article](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/mythspaper.pdf) Prof. [Nick Trefethen](http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/contact/details/trefethen/) addresses this misconception on the right hand side of the first page.

tl;dr

Weierstrass just considers 'a polynomial' as an abstract function, where as Runge's Phenomenon deals with polynomial interpolation at *equidistant points*.

Comment: i firmly believe "tl;dr" is a phenomenon that could have as much impact on mathematical exposition as the term "morality"

Comment: what is "tl;dr"?

Comment: @ILOVEMATH: "Too long; didn't read."

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the Runge phenomenon it the way the polynomial is obtained. I've found a method which nodes converge in the way we want. As you can see in the attachment, the 3th degree polynomial fits better than the quadratic. This is the opposite Runge's phenomenon describes!
[Picture Runge's phenomenon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdBUj.jpg) 
[image]

Comment: Sure. For example, interpolation with [Chebyshev nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes) produces a uniformly convergent sequence of polynomials for $1/(1+x^2)$ on $[-5,5]$.